# Add a static html page in Django

Tags: python, html, django, static

I was wondering if there's a way to add a static html page in django like an "Faq" or "About us" page. if there is a way please let me know

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [TemplateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/) for static page

```
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('about/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="about.html")),
]
```

> TemplateView **should be** used when you want to present some information
> in a html page
>
> TemplateView **shouldn’t** be used when your page has forms and does
> creation or update of objects.