# How can communicate between HTML docs using Django server running via Google Colab notebook?

Tags: python, html, django, google-colaboratory

I want to experiment with this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/WNvxR8RFzBg) and reflect inputs of `Home.html`, which is the summation of them in `result.html` using Django Server running in Google Colab notebook.

I can run the Django server successfully in Google Colab medium, as shown in this [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/zEY1CbN.jpg)
You just need to **manually** set `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['colab.research.google.com']` in `settings.py` once you have installed [django](/questions/tagged/django) library in your cluster.

The problem is I can't communicate and reflect the results of `Home.html` and the summation of them in `result.html`.

I saw in the Tutorial the browser of the local machine when opening HTML docs are:
[image: img]

I tried following the setup, but I could still figure out how to communicate between HTML docs running by Django in Google Colab medium. I think I'm close to a solution, but I still can't manage it.

```py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost']
```

Please feel free to access the [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12zdPUgaMxj-ilv6n_VWT9YmQiXVysBBC?usp=sharing) for quick troubleshooting.

You can quickly create HTML docs using Win [notepad](/questions/tagged/notepad) and save them with `.html`.

`home.html` or download from this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xFKNJpWsNrdHVfGHpGWrhVdN7Dt-Pw64/view?usp=sharing):

```html
<h2> Welcome to my Web </h2>

<form action="result">
    <input type="number" name="no1" placeholder="input1"/>
    <input type="number" name="no2" placeholder="input2"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

---

`result.html` or download from this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/12bC7heFKD_UDqRvwTbxmThpDi_Wrtwul/view?usp=sharing)::

```html
<h1>{{ answer }}</h1>
```

---

The following code is used in the Google Colab notebook to reflect inputs of `Home.html` after summation into `result.html` using Django Server running in the Google Colab cluster. The HTML docs are also updated and available in the cluster before running the Pythonic code.

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponse

# Create your views here
def home(request):
  return render(request, 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/home.html')

def result(request):
  no1 = int(request.GET.get('no1') )
  no2 = int(request.Get.get('no2') )

  answer = no1 + no2

  return render(request, 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/result.html', {'answer' : answer})
```

After running this cell:

```py
!python /content/portfolio/manage.py runserver 8000
#Watching for file changes with StatReloader
#Performing system checks...

#System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

#You have 18 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly #until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions.
#Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
#June 23, 2023 - 13:23:03
#Django version 4.2.2, using settings 'portfolio.settings'
#Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
#Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

#[23/Jun/2023 13:23:03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 10664
#Not Found: /favicon.ico
#[23/Jun/2023 13:23:04] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2124
#[23/Jun/2023 13:28:07] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 10664
#Not Found: /favicon.ico
#[23/Jun/2023 13:28:08] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2124
```

when I click on http://127.0.0.1:8000/ gives me

> This site can’t be reached 127.0.0.1 refused to connect.

I doubled checked proxy settings to ensure that I'm not using a proxy server via: Go to the Chrome menu > Settings > Show advanced settings… > Change proxy settings… > LAN Settings and **deselect** "Use a proxy server for your LAN".

If I click on generated address by the previous line:

```py
from google.colab.output import eval_js
print(eval_js("google.colab.kernel.proxyPort(8000)"))
#https://XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX-8000-colab.googleusercontent.com/
```

I have :
[image: img]

I tried to reflect summation inputs (10 + 20) into `result.html` unsuccessfully:
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/result?no1=10&no2=20` and get again:

> This site can’t be reached 127.0.0.1 refused to connect.

I would be thankful if one could guide me on how to practice Django in [Google Colab] (https://colab.research.google.com/) medium in practice? I find this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60571301/10452700), but not sure if it is the case!

Edit1: today, I attempted using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46026551/10452700) by setting `settings.py` unsuccessfully:

```py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
# start Django server using 
#!python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000
!python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

---

[image: img]

PS: I also activated Localhost on my machine: [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/O3IxG24.jpg)

---

Edit2: I feel that probably instead of inserting `127.0.0.1:8000` in my browser, I need to insert `https://XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX-8000-colab.googleusercontent.com/` I think I also need to include some [URL mapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Home_page#url_mapping) in urls.py using [`TemplateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/class-based-views/) based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50047075/10452700):
[image: img]

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="home.html"))
```

but still, I couldn't manage to fix and establish with HTML pages so far
and get **301 HTTP error** in Django server status

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you wanna do is expose google colab's kernel's localhost to the internet right? to achieve this there are many services, and normally I use ngrok, but for some reason I couldn't get it working in google colab, so in my example, I will use [localtunnel](https://theboroer.github.io/localtunnel-www/) for this.

First thing you wanna do is to run the shells until this cell:

```
%cd portfolio/
```

Once that shell has run, now go to the left panel, and go to `portfolio/portfolio/settings.py`. Double click that file, and then find this line:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
```

Then update it to:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

Then you should modify how you run your django server so that it runs in the background using this code:

```
!nohup python /content/portfolio/manage.py runserver localhost:8000 &
!echo ""
```

Then just after that line, we can start tunneling the `localhost:8000` with localtunnel, using this code:

```
!npm install -g localtunnel

!rm nohup.out
!echo ""

!nohup lt --port 8000 &
!sleep 2 &
!echo "$(<nohup.out )" &
!echo "Endpoint IP:" &
!curl ipv4.icanhazip.com
```

Once you've modified them, you can run all the cells after the `%cd portfolio/` cell. Once you've reached the localtunnel cell and it has been run, you will see a URL and an IP like this:

```
your url is: https://something-something-something.loca.lt
Endpoint IP:
34.125.224.107
```

You can access with that URL, but you will be asked to input an IP, you can see below the URL, there will be an IP, and copy & paste that IP to the URL, and voila.

Here is the updated notebook:
[image: Open In Colab]

Comment: Thanks for your input. Did you manage to reflect the results of `home.html` into `result.html `? if so, how?

Comment: I feel that your solution using *LocalTunnel* is (generated URL + End point IP) alternative way for `https://XXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX-8000-colab.googleusercontent.com/`. Can you explain how I can configure `urlpatterns` maybe to reflect the results of `home.html` into `result.html` to complete the task?

Comment: *I want to experiment with this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/WNvxR8RFzBg) and reflect inputs of `Home.html`, which is the summation of them in `result.html` using Django Server running in Google Colab notebook.*